# Google Map Tiles Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have custom radar tiles that I am trying to overlay over Google Maps in an Android application.  My question is how do I know what Google tiles are currently showing on my phone device to know which of my custom tiles to load on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that Android does it the same way as the JavaScript Maps API v3 does it, but since it probably does:

You can review the info here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#CustomMapTypes.

A specific tile is specified by three things:  the zoom level, the x coordinate, and the y coordinate.  Based on the info in the above link, you can determine what area of the world to render as a 256x256 tile based on those three integers.  Pay special attention to the "Tile Coordinates" section of the above document.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have your tiles keyed. It is likely going to be easier to just pull the correct tile from your deck, rather than trying to figure out what google maps is displaying. You should have everything you need to do this (or be easily able to calculate it) because you have the latitude and longitude of the center of the screen as well as the bounds of the screen (in lat/lon) and the zoom level.

Are you looking for code to illustrate this, or just an idea of the best way to go about it?